# If $A$ & $B$ are $4\times 4$ matrices with $\det(A)=-5$ & $\det(B)=10$ then evaluate...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ & $B$ are $4\times 4$ matrices with $\det(A)=-5 $ & $\det(B)=10$ then evaluate...

a) $\det\left(A+\operatorname{adj}\left(A^{-1}\right)\right)$

b) $\det(A+B)$

Yes, those are meant to be addition signs. I wouldn't be asking if it were multiplication. ANS for a) is $-256/125.$

Comment: There's not enough information to answer these.

Comment: It should be that is all I have in my book.

Comment: If these matrices were being multiplied, then yes we could evaluate them quite easily: $det(AB) = det(A) * det(b)$

Comment: If the plus sign were replaced with times these could be answered.  But not as they are stated herem

Comment: The answer in my book for a) is -256/125 if this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You have from wikipedia or maybe your book somewhere derived that: $${\bf A}adj({\bf A}) = det({\bf A}){\bf I}$$
which is also true for the inverse matrix if it exists:
$${\bf A}^{-1}adj({\bf A}^{-1}) = det({\bf A}^{-1}){\bf I}$$

Multiplying both sides $\bf A$ gives $adj({\bf A}^{-1}) = det({\bf A}^{-1}){\bf A}$

Plug that adj expression in and maybe you can take it from there.

Answer (score 4):

Answer to a):

It holds that:
$$ A \cdot \operatorname{adj(A)} = \det (A) \cdot I .$$

Thus, we have:
$$ A^{-1}\cdot \operatorname{adj}\left(A^{-1}\right) = \det \left(A^{-1}\right) \cdot I.$$

However, $\det\left(A^{-1}\right) = -\frac{1}{5}$ and you need to apply the identity $\det(\lambda A) = \lambda^n \det A,$ where $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and $\lambda \in \mathbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

For part (b) it is easy to show that the answer is not determined.  For example, let $A=diag(-5,1,1,1)$, $B_1=diag(10,1,1,1)$, and $B_2=diag(10,1,-1,-1)$.  Then $\det A=-5$, $\det B_1=10=\det B_2$, but $\det(A+B_1)=40$, while $\det(A+B_2)=0$.